# How does UUID least and UUID most effect the UUID of the mob you summon in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How does the `UUIDMost` and `UUIDLeast` tags affect the UUID of the the mob you're summoning in? I've looked all over and the best in-depth (from what I can see) wiki on it is in German, and frankly google translate doesn't translate good enough.

This is the link to the German wiki: http://minecraft-de.gamepedia.com/UUID

So can anyone give me info on this? I have like no info on how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the `UUID` is divided into two halfs of 16 characters. The two halfs are both hexadecimal numbers, just as the `UUID` itself. The hexadecimal numbers of the two halfs are then converted to two normal decimal numbers. The `UUIDLeast` is the decimal number with the least significant bits, while `UUIDMost` is the decimal number with the most significant bits. To convert the hexadecimal number into a decimal number, you can use [this converter](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html).

(Sources: [this](http://minecraft-de.gamepedia.com/UUID), [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2530432-uuidleast-and-uuidmost-what-do-they-truely-do) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier))

Comment: There are a few pretty good alternatives to that converter, such as asciitohex.com and even Windows' built-in calculator (when set to programmer mode)

Answer (score -3):

A UUIDLeast of 1 and UUIDMost of 2 creates hexadecimal value: 00000000-0000-0002-0000-000000000001

Better explained at:
[http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2530432-uuidleast-and-uuidmost-what-do-they-truely-do](http://A%20UUIDLeast%20of%201%20and%20UUIDMost%20of%202%20creates%20hexadecimal%20value:%2000000000-0000-0002-0000-000000000001)

Comment: You literally just copied something said in the top reply of the post. Either paraphrase, or if you must quote, elaborate on the quote